# Set A Default Value On A LOOKUP Field

Tags: process-builder, lookup

Has anyone found a way to **set a DEFAULT value on a LOOKUP field** for new records?  The research I've done shows this is an Idea at SF currently, and I do not see a workaround.

I've tried Process Builder, and am afraid I may have to revert to Apex with Before and/or After logic.

The goal is to NOT have to use Apex *(directly - PB and Flow are fine).*

[Idea - Set Default Value on Lookup Field](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000007PidAAE)

Comment: Why can"t you just use Process Builder? What's the problem you encounter?

Comment: I am using ROOTSTOCK ERP, and there is a checkbox that (must be) turned on upon record creation, which uses Apex to create a Customer Master record (that mirrors the Account record).  There is always a danger of cyclic relationships, and if, during the CREATION of the Account record, I try to SELECTIVELY SET this field (if it isn't set by the user first), it fails because the CUSTOMER MASTER process builder uses that same field. . . . . .

Now that I've typed that:  I am going to try a different approach, as tying it out gave me a new idea.  Will update if it helps.

Comment: By cyclic relationships, I mean cyclic UPDATES actually - Account to Customer to Account, before the record is committed.

Comment: I hope you already solved this issue. But just for the record: This is indeed an idea currently investigated by the development teams, but there is an app in the app exchange providing just what you need as it seems. I haven't tried it but from the description it should do the trick: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wj3REAQ